# add content to uib-tooltip-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Why does this work just fine:

Controller:

```
$scope.getHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>Test</div>");
```

View:

```
<div uib-tooltip-html="getHtml">Test</div>
```

But the following doesn't work at all? ;-(

Controller:

```
$scope.getHtml = function (){
        var textOutput = "<div>Text</div>";
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(textOutput);        
    };
```

View:

```
<div uib-tooltip-html="getHtml()">Test</div>
```

Error message is: angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

---

Edit 1: Thank you, original problem solved. But now I have another question on this one. What if the `<div>` is within a ngRepeat and I want to give the function an item of ngRepeat as an argument? Like `<div uib-tooltip-html="getHtml({{item}})">Test</div>`
?

---

Edit 2: Here is a more specific example of my problem. I want something like this to work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="object in objectArray">
    <td uib-tooltip-html="getHtml(object.value1)">{{object.value1}}<td>
    <td uib-tooltip-html="getHtml(object.value2)">{{object.value2}}<td>
    <td uib-tooltip-html="getHtml(object.value3)">{{object.value3}}<td>
</tr>
```

with

```
$scope.getHtml = function (value) {
    var textOutput = doSomethingWithObjectDataAndCreateHtmlFromIt(value);
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(textOutput);        
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I use `uib-tooltip` instead of `uib-tooltip-html` I can see the tooltip with the correct html (unparsed) in it, but if I change it to `uib-tooltip-html` there's the error again.

Answer (score 0):

In the **first** case `$scope.getHtml` ends up to be a **string**.

In the **second** case `$scope.getHtml` ends up to be a **function**, which returns the same string as the first case.

However if you call your function in the second case, it would work, as it is essentially the same code:

```
$scope.getHtml = function () {
    var textOutput = "<div>Text</div>";
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(textOutput);        
} ()
```

if you want to pass the html data in ng-repeat, just do this:

```
$scope.getHtml = function (html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);        
}
```

and use it by:

```
<div uib-tooltip-html="getHtml()">Test</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! Spent all day on this :D

Comment: Now I have one more question on this. I've edited my original post for it.

Comment: Remove the templating syntax and it should work just fine: <div uib-tooltip-html="getHtml(item)">Test</div>

Comment: But where do I put the argument in the function?

Comment: `$scope.getHtml = function (item) {` ? I added this to my answer.

Comment: yea, remove the `()` at the end. You get it, right? The `()` at the end will call itself and provide a string instead of function that we are expecting now by using it with the parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to be a pain in the ass, but I edited my question again to ask more specifically about my second problem on it. Thank you a lot!